# Blazor 3.2 Component is throwing a null reference exception on child

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I am trying to make a blazor templated component similar to the one in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1 but with a nested sub table.

The parent table is working as expected but a null ref exception is being thrown on the binding of the ChildRowTemplate (highlighted in attached code). The model is one Agent many Complexes.

The Template

```
 @typeparam TItem

<table>
<thead>
    <tr>@TableHeader</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        <tr> The error 
            @if (OnCollapse.HasDelegate)
            {
                <td>
                    <button class="primary-button mb-1" @onclick="@(_=>HandleCollapse(item))">Toggle Complexes</button>
                </td>
            }  
            @RowTemplate(item)
        </tr>
        <tr>
            @ChildRowTemplate(item)
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>@TableFooter</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>

 @code {

[Parameter]
public RenderFragment TableHeader { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public RenderFragment<TItem> RowTemplate { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public RenderFragment<TItem> ChildRowTemplate { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public RenderFragment TableFooter { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public IReadOnlyList<TItem> Items { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public EventCallback<object> OnCollapse { get; set; }

   void HandleCollapse(TItem item)
   {
      OnCollapse.InvokeAsync(item);
   }
}
```

The code

```
<TableTemplate Items="@Agents" OnCollapse="toggle" Context="agent">
        <TableHeader>
            <th><button class="outline-button">Add Agent</button></th>
            <th>Co. Name</th>
            <th>Co. Number</th>
            <th>Admin</th>
            <th>Admin Email</th>
            <th>Admin Phone</th>
        </TableHeader>
        <RowTemplate>
            <td>@agent.CompanyName</td>
            <td>@agent.CompanyNumber</td>
            <td>@agent.AdminFirstName @agent.AdminLastName</td>
            <td>@agent.AdminEmail</td>
            <td>@agent.AdminPhoneNumber</td>
        </RowTemplate>
        <ChildRowTemplate Context="agent">
            <TableTemplate Items="@agent.Complexes"> @*<--- NULL REF *@ 
                <TableHeader>
                    <th>Complex Name</th>
                    <th>Is Active</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                </TableHeader>
                <RowTemplate Context="complex">
                    <td>@complex.Name</td>
                    <td>@complex.IsActive</td>
                    <td>@complex.DisplayAddress</td>
                </RowTemplate>
            </TableTemplate>
        </ChildRowTemplate>
        <TableFooter></TableFooter>
    </TableTemplate>
```

Comment: How sure are you that `agent.Complexes != null` for all agents?

Comment: Completely sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your error and I found the issue as far as I can tell. It stems from how your table template is handling the `ChildRowTemplate` fragment.

First, to clarify, I mocked some data to feed the tables in the code behind of my page like below. This assured that I had nested data with no null values, as you indicated in your comment that you know you don't have a null value in your `agent.Complexes` property.

```cs
@code {

    public List<ListItem> Items { get; set; } = new List<ListItem>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Items.Add(new ListItem()
            {
                Name = $"List Item #{i}",
                NestedItems = new List<NestedItem>()
            });

            foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                for (var j = 1; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    item.NestedItems.Add(new NestedItem()
                    {
                        Name = $"Item {i} contains nested item {j}"
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class ListItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<NestedItem> NestedItems { get; set; }
    }

    public class NestedItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I set up the table just like you have it, though a bit simpler on actual table structure, and ran the app. Null Reference Exception just like you had. Error reproduced.

```cs
<TableTemplate Items="Items" Context="item">
    <TableHeader>
        <th>Item Name</th>
    </TableHeader>
    <RowTemplate>
        <tr>@item.Name</tr>
    </RowTemplate>
    <ChildRowTemplate>
        <TableTemplate Items="item.NestedItems" Context="nestItem">
            <TableHeader>
                <th>Nested Item Name</th>
            </TableHeader>
            <RowTemplate>
                <tr>@nestItem.Name</tr>
            </RowTemplate>
        </TableTemplate>
    </ChildRowTemplate>
    <TableFooter></TableFooter>
</TableTemplate>
```

Then, I added a null check in the template component to handle scenarios where you DON'T set the `ChildRowTemplateComponent`, so it only renders when there is something to render, like so:

```cs
.....
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        <tr>
            @if (OnCollapse.HasDelegate)
            {
                <td>
                    <button class="primary-button mb-1" @onclick="@(_=>HandleCollapse(item))">Toggle Complexes</button>
                </td>
            }
            @RowTemplate(item)
        </tr>
        @if (ChildRowTemplate != null) @*<<<<< Note the null check!*@
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@ChildRowTemplate(item)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</tbody>
....
```

Ran the app, no more exception. The tables will need to be tweaked and styled, but you knew that already and this gets the app running as expected.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Nik - I moved away from templating components until a get a better understanding but will get back to them soon. Your update makes sense.